# Set composition( set theory)

Tags: probability-theory

Prove that $A\circ C \subset (A\circ B) \cup (B\circ C)$,

Here are my thoughts. Let $M=A\circ C  ,  N=A\circ B,  Q= (B\circ C), P =(A\circ B) \cup (B\circ C)$. I tried the cases where $x \in M$, but $x \in A$  and  $x\notin C$, and the case where $x \in N \, , x \in P$ and $ x \notin Q$. But after doing all these cases, I do not know how to continue. I have to use this proof to show that the probability of $P(A\circ C) \leq  P(A\circ B) + P(B\circ C)$

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! I tidied up your question a bit, I tried to retain the original meaning. Could you explain what set composition means in this context?

Comment: Likely he means composition of events, one event followed by another.  This has nothing to do with set theory but probablity instead, as he states in his last sentence.

Comment: by composition I am referring to the hollow-circle : that $A∘B =$ (A U B) \ ( A n B)